# Update Kafka in Kubernetes causes downtime

Tags: kubernetes, apache-kafka, spring-kafka, kubernetes-statefulset

I'm running a 4 brokers Kafka cluster in Kubernetes. The replication factor is 3 and ISR is 2.

In addition, there's a producer service (running Spring stream) generating messages and a consumer service reading from the topic. Now I tried to update the Kafka cluster with a rolling update, hoping for no downtime, but during the update, the producer's log was filled with this error:

```
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.NotLeaderForPartitionException: This server is not the leader for that topic-partition.
```

According to my calculation, when 1 broker is down there shouldn't be a problem because the min ISR is 2. However, it seems like the producer service is unaware of the rolling update and keep sending messages to the same broker...

Any ideas how to solve it?

This is my kafka.yaml

```
apiVersion: apps/v1beta1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: kafka
  namespace: default
  labels:
    app: kafka
spec:
  serviceName: kafka
  replicas: 4
  updateStrategy:
    type: RollingUpdate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: kafka
      annotations:
        prometheus.io/scrape: "true"
        prometheus.io/port: "9308"
    spec:
      nodeSelector:
        middleware.node: "true"
      imagePullSecrets:
      - name: nexus-registry
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 300
      containers:
      - name: kafka
        image: kafka:2.12-2.1.0
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent

        resources:
          limits:
            cpu: 3000m
            memory: 1800Mi
          requests:
            cpu: 2000m
            memory: 1800Mi
        env:

        # Replication
        - name: KAFKA_DEFAULT_REPLICATION_FACTOR
          value: "3"
        - name: KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR
          value: "3"
        - name: KAFKA_MIN_INSYNC_REPLICAS
          value: "2"

        # Protocol Version
        - name: KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_PROTOCOL_VERSION
          value: "2.1"
        - name: KAFKA_LOG_MESSAGE_FORMAT_VERSION
          value: "2.1"

        - name: ENABLE_AUTO_EXTEND
          value: "true"
        - name: KAFKA_DELETE_TOPIC_ENABLE
          value: "true"
        - name: KAFKA_RESERVED_BROKER_MAX_ID
          value: "999999999"
        - name: KAFKA_AUTO_CREATE_TOPICS_ENABLE
          value: "true"
        - name: KAFKA_PORT
          value: "9092"
        - name: KAFKA_ADVERTISED_PORT
          value: "9092"
        - name: KAFKA_NUM_RECOVERY_THREADS_PER_DATA_DIR
          value: "10"
        - name: KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_REPLICATION_FACTOR
          value: "3"
        - name: KAFKA_LOG_RETENTION_BYTES
          value: "1800000000000"
        - name: KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: status.podIP
        - name: KAFKA_OFFSETS_RETENTION_MINUTES
          value: "10080"
        - name: KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT
          valueFrom:
            configMapKeyRef:
              name: zk-config
              key: zk.endpoints
        - name: KAFKA_LOG_DIRS
          value: /kafka/kafka-logs
        ports:
        - name: kafka
          containerPort: 9092
        - name: prometheus
          containerPort: 7071
        volumeMounts:
        - name: data
          mountPath: /kafka
        readinessProbe:
          tcpSocket:
            port: 9092
          timeoutSeconds: 1
          failureThreshold: 12
          initialDelaySeconds: 10
          periodSeconds: 30
          successThreshold: 1
      - name: kafka-exporter
        image: danielqsj/kafka-exporter:latest
        resources:
          requests:
            cpu: 100m
            memory: 100Mi
          limits:
            cpu: 500m
            memory: 500Mi
        ports:
        - containerPort: 9308
  volumeClaimTemplates:
  - metadata:
      name: data
      labels:
        app: kafka
    spec:
      accessModes:
      - ReadWriteOnce
      resources:
        requests:
          storage: 2000Gi
```

Comment: Can you please post the relevant producer code, including the Kafka access string?

Comment: Does the producer need to be configured with acks=all?
Also, does the consumer need to have auto.commit=false and be transactional? (at least once processing is needed?)

Comment: Were you able to figure out the problem?